# Does this residual graph show bias?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear

A linear regression model generated the below residuals plot. How should we interpret this in terms of mean-zero error assumption? Is the assumption violated or not? Does this show bias?

[image: Linear Regression Residuals Plot]

Answer (score 3):

The downward sloping part on the left side of the graphs indicate a lower bound on the dependent variable that "bites". In your case the dependent variable seems to be salary, so the lower bound is probably 0. So I would look again closely at whether the linearity assumption is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Check also whether your model predicts negative salary for any players.